# Flexible Border Radius

Tags: html, css

[image]I have some anchor tags. I am applying border radius to them so that they looks inside a round shape (CIRCLE). It must flexible to their text width. I am trying but not getting what to do.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cUtLk/)

How can I achieve that? please any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
<a href="http://google.com">abc</a>
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/">abcdefgh</a>
```

css:

```
a{

    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
-moz-border-radius: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you want all your anchor tags to have the same shape (round) ?

Comment: But that is what I need to do. ..:(

Comment: you have conflicting requirements. Your anchor tags cannot all be (1) round and (2) with variable width; at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give radius in percentage.

CSS:

```
a{

    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10%;
    -moz-border-radius: 10%;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
```

Here is [<kbd>Updated fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/cUtLk/4/)

From border radius this is not possible to get same circle around anchor because it depends on anchor text size. if it is different it reflect circle also.

**Update:**

You can do this with `div` by giving then width and height: [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/rkEMR/1936/)

[Another Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/aplvrmue)

Comment: From what I understood, he wants all his anchor tags to be round and to have the same size.

Comment: give border-radius 50%, but for large texts it will be ellipse and not perfect circle

Comment: correct @DurgeshChaudhary but that will not same for all. Updated my answer also

Comment: It is good to have rounded rectangle for your case or you can also circle if your text are going to be of fixed size like some count or some thing like that

Comment: I have modified my question

Comment: There is another option available to set height equal to width so that ellipse turns out to be a circle. More info here : http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: acchha. Can I dynamically set the border radius at runtime depending on the text size of anchor tag, using jQuery

Comment: ya @LogicBurner See update you can set width and height in percentage see updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Manwal. It really helps. Remaining part I can do now. Thanks a lot